# Why does this explain indicate an index was not used?

Tags: mongodb, indexing, mongodb-query, explain

Given the following query:

```
var exp = db.messages.explain('executionStats')

exp.find( { 'headers.Date' : { '$gt' : new Date(2001,3,1) } }, { 'headers.From' : 1, '_id' : 0 } ).sort( { 'headers.From' : 1 } )
```

That produces the following output:

```
{
  "queryPlanner" : {
    "plannerVersion" : 1,
    "namespace" : "enron.messages",
    "indexFilterSet" : false,
    "parsedQuery" : {
      "headers.Date" : {
        "$gt" : ISODate("2001-04-01T05:00:00Z")
      }
    },
    "winningPlan" : {
      "stage" : "PROJECTION",
      "transformBy" : {
        "headers.From" : 1,
        "_id" : 0
      },
      "inputStage" : {
        "stage" : "FETCH",
        "filter" : {
          "headers.Date" : {
            "$gt" : ISODate("2001-04-01T05:00:00Z")
          }
        },
        "inputStage" : {
          "stage" : "IXSCAN",
          "keyPattern" : {
            "headers.From" : 1
          },
          "indexName" : "headers.From_1",
          "isMultiKey" : false,
          "direction" : "forward",
          "indexBounds" : {
            "headers.From" : [
              "[MinKey, MaxKey]"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "rejectedPlans" : [ ]
  },
  "executionStats" : {
    "executionSuccess" : true,
    "nReturned" : 83057,
    "executionTimeMillis" : 726,
    "totalKeysExamined" : 120477,
    "totalDocsExamined" : 120477,
    "executionStages" : {
      "stage" : "PROJECTION",
      "nReturned" : 83057,
      "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 690,
      "works" : 120478,
      "advanced" : 83057,
      "needTime" : 37420,
      "needFetch" : 0,
      "saveState" : 941,
      "restoreState" : 941,
      "isEOF" : 1,
      "invalidates" : 0,
      "transformBy" : {
        "headers.From" : 1,
        "_id" : 0
      },
      "inputStage" : {
        "stage" : "FETCH",
        "filter" : {
          "headers.Date" : {
            "$gt" : ISODate("2001-04-01T05:00:00Z")
          }
        },
        "nReturned" : 83057,
        "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 350,
        "works" : 120478,
        "advanced" : 83057,
        "needTime" : 37420,
        "needFetch" : 0,
        "saveState" : 941,
        "restoreState" : 941,
        "isEOF" : 1,
        "invalidates" : 0,
        "docsExamined" : 120477,
        "alreadyHasObj" : 0,
        "inputStage" : {
          "stage" : "IXSCAN",
          "nReturned" : 120477,
          "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 60,
          "works" : 120477,
          "advanced" : 120477,
          "needTime" : 0,
          "needFetch" : 0,
          "saveState" : 941,
          "restoreState" : 941,
          "isEOF" : 1,
          "invalidates" : 0,
          "keyPattern" : {
            "headers.From" : 1
          },
          "indexName" : "headers.From_1",
          "isMultiKey" : false,
          "direction" : "forward",
          "indexBounds" : {
            "headers.From" : [
              "[MinKey, MaxKey]"
            ]
          },
          "keysExamined" : 120477,
          "dupsTested" : 0,
          "dupsDropped" : 0,
          "seenInvalidated" : 0,
          "matchTested" : 0
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "serverInfo" : {
    "host" : "dpercy-mac-air.local",
    "port" : 27017,
    "version" : "3.0.1",
    "gitVersion" : "534b5a3f9d10f00cd27737fbcd951032248b5952"
  },
  "ok" : 1
}
```

What in the explain says that the query did NOT use an index? From my understanding the following section implies that an index was used because the winning plan has an `IXSCAN` stage in it:

```
"winningPlan" : {
      "stage" : "PROJECTION",
      "transformBy" : {
        "headers.From" : 1,
        "_id" : 0
      },
      "inputStage" : {
        "stage" : "FETCH",
        "filter" : {
          "headers.Date" : {
            "$gt" : ISODate("2001-04-01T05:00:00Z")
          }
        },
        "inputStage" : {
          "stage" : "IXSCAN",
          "keyPattern" : {
            "headers.From" : 1
          },
          "indexName" : "headers.From_1",
          "isMultiKey" : false,
          "direction" : "forward",
          "indexBounds" : {
            "headers.From" : [
              "[MinKey, MaxKey]"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
```

But I'm being told that this query did not use an index. Why is that?

Comment: Where do you see no index was used? `IXSCAN` is short for "IndeXSCAN" as opposed to "COLLSCAN", which is short for "COLLection SCAN".

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg Please reread my question. I'm saying that an index scan WAS used for the find, and am being told otherwise.

Comment: Who told you? Plain and simple, he, she or it is wrong. What is true however, is that I read your question too fast – sorry for that. Is it possible that he/she/it was talking of a [covered query](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/query-optimization/#covered-query)?

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg The statement was made by an exam question from Mongo University (exam is over now), so I'm inclined to trust them. The answer shows that the following statement is false: The query used an index to figure out which documents match the find criteria.

Comment: Argh, need to go to bed! ;) The query was on `headers.Date` so actually, during the lookup, the index was not used (presumably, there is none on said field). During the `FETCH` phase (when the documents which match the *query* are already determined), the index was utilized however to find the documents which match the projection and subsequently sort accordingly. Have a good night!

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg, where do you see that during `lookup` the index was not used?

Comment: @akostadinov Have a close look at `inputStage.indexName`